# Flickering browser tab while editing

Tags: bug, design

While reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/8242529) I got distracted during typing with flickering of the browser's tab text.

The text seems to get redrawn on every keystroke while editing the body of the post (not its title). I have noticed something before, but not investigated this.

I suspect it has to do with the code snippet in the text, as this only occurs if there is a code snippet in the text.

A GIF version of a small part of it, each time you press a key or type, the tab icon changes to the spinning "loading" one, the **text changes as well** saying "Connecting" and is then replaced with the original tab title:

[image]

---

A video of the "real thing" can be viewed [here](http://www.ruamel.eu/download/dc397bb8-caa3-4407-bdac-b9c2f9670d90/so_flickr.mp4)

(Firefox 38, on Linux Mint 17 Rebecca)

Comment: I get this too, Linux mint 17.

Comment: Have you got a screenshot so that you can use a freehand red circle to show the flickering? Oh. I suppose not.

Comment: Repro (for the tab's icon, at least), Chrome 43 (wtf) Win7

Comment: @BillWoodger, Your wishes have come true, the question now includes an animated GIF with a freehand red arrow :-)

Comment: This is caused by the Stack Snippet. It is reproducible while editing any post that contains a Stack Snippet, not just from a review queue.

Comment: No repro on OS X 10.10.3 Safari 8.0.6, Chrome 43, Firefox 40.0a2.

Comment: @bjb568, The post has to contain a stack snippet, does it ?

Comment: Oh wait, I just repro'd it in FF, but still no repro in Safari and Chrome.